# Conditional type with a Union

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm merging two arrays which contain data of different types. Using the union of the two types, it looks like this:

```
interface Animal {
  animalid: number;
  species: string;
}

interface Person {
  personid: number;
  name: string;
}

const animals: Animal[] = getAnimals();
const people: Person[] = getPeople();

const bothThings: (Animal|Person)[] = [...animals, ...people];
```

I want to be able to call a function passing in the id of the animal or person, but the id is in a different property depending on the type: `animalid` or `personid` respectively. I can work out which property I need and therefore which type it is based on the id property but I can't use it because I get a TypeScript error: `Property 'animalid' does not exist on type 'Animal|Person'. Property 'animalid' does not exist on type 'Person'.`.

```
const indexOfThing: number;
let id: number;

...

if (bothThings[indexOfThing].hasOwnProperty('animalid')) {
  id = bothThings[indexOfThing].animalid // TypeScript Error
} else if (bothThings[indexOfThing].hasOwnProperty('personid')) {
  id = bothThings[indexOfThing].personid // TypeScript Error
}

functionThatNeedsId(id);
```

How can I correctly set the type depending on the conditional, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: What does Animal[] or Person[] actually look like?

Comment: @basic These are just examples but I've now included a possible interface for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
if (bothThings[indexOfThing].hasOwnProperty('animalid')) {
  id = (bothThings[indexOfThing] as Animal).animalid
} else if (bothThings[indexOfThing].hasOwnProperty('personid')) {
  id = (bothThings[indexOfThing] as Person).personid
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The confusion is that while you narrow the type down at runtime using `hasOwnProperty`, you don't actually do so at compile time and therefore the compiler is complaining.

You can resolve this using [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

If you do something like the following then it might possibly work:

```
const animals: Animal[] = getAnimals();
const people: Person[] = getPeople();

function isAnimal(animalOrPerson : Animal|Person) : animalOrPerson is Animal {
    return (object as Animal).animalid !== undefined;
} 

function isPerson(animalOrPerson  : Animal|Person) : animalOrPerson is Person {
    return (object as Person).personid!== undefined;
} 


const bothThings: (Animal|Person)[] = [...animals, ...people];

if (isAnimal(bothThings[indexOfThing])) {
  id = bothThings[indexOfThing].animalid 
} else if (isPerson(bothThings[indexOfThing].hasOwnProperty('personid'))) {
  id = bothThings[indexOfThing].personid 
}
```

Doing this will enable the compiler to correctly determine the actual type of the object within the conditions.